# Modes in optical fibers

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology, fiber-optics

I am trying to understand the modes in step-index optical fibers and I saw that they say the electric field distribution in the core and cladding is as bellow. my question is that which component of electric field is this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

"TE" means "Transverse Electrical". That means these modes have E-field perpendicular to the axis of the fiber. Because the fiber is circularly symmetric, the E field could point in any direction perpendicular to the axis (we say that the modes in different polarizations are *degenerate*).

However, circular dielectric waveguide like step-index optical fiber does not actually have TE modes. The actual modes in optical fiber are called [LP](https://www.rp-photonics.com/lp_modes.html) (linearly polarized), HE, and HM (hybrid electric or magnetic) modes. These modes have E-field that is not exactly perpendicular to the fiber axis. They will behave approximately like TE modes, but not exactly. The approximation will be better, the stronger the index contrast between core and cladding.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I mean is the z component of the electric field or r or phi components of the electric field? because I want to plot HE electric filed but I do not know which component I have to plot I just think that  it is z component

Comment: If "z" is the fiber axis, then "perpendicular to the fiber axis" means there is no z component. The TE modes (if they exist) have zero E-field in the z-direction. The LP mode is linearly polarized: E-field is either in the x or y direction, depending which polarization. That means the $r$ and $\phi$ components will be different at different locations in the transverse plane.

Comment: sorry but I think I can not understand what you mean maybe that is because I have just started learning about optical fibers.  suppose that I have HE11 (fundamental mode) and it has both x and y components of the electric field and I want to plot the field and I know that in the cladding it is decaying but I do not know this plot demonstrates which component @The Photon

Comment: The E-Field is circularly symmetric about the z-axis.  So, it doesn't matter which way you slice it, or what you call 'x' and what you call 'y'.

Comment: @The Photon thank you very much for your kind answers

Answer (score 1):

As The Photon already pointed out, "TE" means "Transverse Electrical", which is just telling you that there is no component along the direction of propagation - $z$, in this case. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_mode#Waveguide_modes) for the distinction.

Now, if you want to find the functional form of your electric field, you have to solve the wave equation. 
Since your problem is cylindrically symmetric around $z$, the direction of propagation, your solution will exhibit the same symmetry.

These solutions have a name, the [Laguerre-Gassian modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam#Laguerre-Gaussian_modes), which look like this:

$$ E(r, \phi, z) \propto e^{-\frac{r^2}{w^2(z)}}\cdot e^{-il\phi}\cdot e^{-ikz}. $$

You can see that the $\phi$ dependence is in a pure phase factor.

What you actually see on a camera is the **intenstiy** $I \propto E^{\dagger}E$ so $$ I \propto e^{-2\frac{r^2}{w^2(z)}}.$$

So only the radial part remains, and you can drop the $\phi $ depdendence from $E(r, \phi, z) \propto e^{-\frac{r^2}{w^2(z)}}$. Which is exactly what is plotted in your drawings. The $y$ axis is $r$.

(I have just written the fundamental mode, which is a gaussian, like your $TE_0$, on the Wiki link you can see that there is an $l$ dependent spatial part, which is what gives you the different shape of the other $TE$ modes: for details look at the Mathematica script below:

[image])

Comment: I have seen that you are also active on Mathematica, so I have added a short script to reproduce your field profiles.

Comment: Thanks for the Mathematica code. I tried to solve my problem as you said but I have a problem: after solving Maxwell's equations the r dependence of my electric field is like Bessel functions and I chose cos(lϕ) instead of exponential dependence. so in the core, I have BesselJ and in the cladding I have BesselK. and after plotting it I can not obtain the desired plot @SuperCiocia

Comment: Yeah this is the typical problem of when to take the real part of the electric field. Your way of taking the real part immediately is the correct one. But then you get a time dependent $\cos^2$ in the intensity. So what you do, is take the time average, $\langle \cos^2 \rangle  = 1/2$. You can take the average because the oscillation happens at $100$s of THz frequencies so extremely fast. The "advantage" of working with complex field and taking the intensity as $E^{\dagger}E$ is that it does the time-averaging automatically.

Comment: Actually sorry my comment is wrong, I thought you were referring to the $z$ phase factor. Let me think about it. Sorry.

Comment: OKay. Here it is.Laguerre-Gauss modes are not the *real* solutions of the full wave equation, but of an approximation of the latter known as the *paraxial Helmholtz equation*. This equation is **actually** complex because there is a factor of $i$ appearing, so the complext exponential as a solution is not just a maths trick, it's the real solution. You cannot just take the real part. You have to keep both terms. However you can use my reasoning that the $\phi$ term does not give rise to an intensity dependence upon $E^{\dagger}E$, so you can drop it.

Comment: @ SuperCiocia thank you very much for your kind answers so if I suppose that my maxwell's equations solution is like E=R(r)ϕ(ϕ)Z(z) I just can take R†R which means the BesselJ*BesselJ? because I can not achieve the desired plot with that because I saw in the books that the plots you sent me are the correct ones

Comment: The thing is, for this problem you wouldn’t solve the entire Wave equation but jus the paraxial Helmholtz equation, which I know the LG beams are solutions to. I never tried to solve the wave equation. Where do you get the Bessel function from?

Comment: I solved the equation by doing the separation of variables and then for the r dependence it came out that Bessel function is the answer. you can find more information here: https://nptel.ac.in/courses/117101002/downloads/Lec05.pdf

Comment: So first off you can see that you are already working with the Hemholtz equation, i.e. a scalar equation and not a vector one (at the end of page 6 when you switch to $\psi$). Then on page 7, whne they say "the field should have $z$ variation as $^{-jβz}$", that is the start of the paraxial approximation. But regardless, you are using a complex field here to get another equation (the one with $\beta$ that appears hereafter). So that equation now is a *complex* equation. You cannot go back to the real part. You should have plugged in $cos(\beta z)$.

Comment: FYI for optical fibres I would suggest this amazing book: https://eceagmr.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/optical-fiber-communications-principles-and-pr.pdf

Comment: @ SuperCiocia I hope to find the answer of my question in this book thank you very much

Comment: Did you find anything in the end?

Comment: @ SuperCiocia yes I studied the book you sent and also some other papers and books and finally, I understood (I think so) the concept of modes in optical fibers. thank you very much